# How to create conversational skills using Flask-Ask, Amazon Alexa and Python 3 backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, python-3.6, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on my final project for my Bachelor degree in software development. The project requires students to pick a topic related to software development and write a paper based on their findings.

## Problem Definition

Here's what I need help with:

My topic is on developing skills for Amazon Alexa using Python 3. The current focus is creating **custom skills**.

My custom skill will calculate the volume of an object.

For the purposes of this question an object is a box, cube, cylinder, or sphere. I am having trouble getting the volume of a box. I need help getting the values from the user to my Python 3 backend.

I want the dialogue to go something like this:

**Alexa**: "Welcome to Volume Calculator. Would you like to calculate the volume of an object?"

**User**: "Yes"

**Alexa**: "Which object would you like me to calculate the volume of?"

**User**: "A Box"

**Alexa**: "What is the length of the box?"

**User**: "5"

**Alexa**: "What is the width of the box?"

**User**: "5"

**Alexa**: "What is the height of the box?"

**User**: "5"

**Alexa** "The volume of the box is one-hundred and twenty-five cubic meters."

The current response from Alexa is "There was a problem with the requested skill's response."

### Python 3 Backend

```
@ask.intent("BoxLengthIntent", convert={"length": int})
def box_length():
box_length_prompt = "What is the length of the box?"
return question(box_length_prompt)


@ask.intent("BoxWidthIntent", convert={"width": int})
def box_width():
box_length_prompt = "What is the width of the box?"
return question(box_length_prompt)


@ask.intent("BoxHeightIntent", convert={"height": int})
def box_height():
box_height_prompt = "What is the height of the box?"
return question(box_height_prompt)


@ask.intent("BoxVolumeIntent", convert={"length": int, "width": int, 
"height": int})
def calculate_box_volume():
length = box_length()
# session.attributes["length"] = length

width = box_width()
# session.attributes["width"] = width

height = box_height()
# session.attributes["height"] = height

# Question does not define mul. Program crashes here.
volume_of_box = length * width * height 

msg = "The volume of the box is {} cubic meters"\
    .format(volume_of_box)
return statement(msg).simple_card(title="VolumeCalculator", content=msg)
```

#### Intent Schema

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "YesIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "NoIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "CubeIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "length",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "CubeVolumeIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "length",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "BoxVolumeIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "length",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
          "name": "width",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
          "name": "height",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Sample Utterances

BoxVolumeIntent box

BoxVolumeIntent give me the volume of a box

BoxVolumeIntent give me the volume of a box with length {length} height

{height} and width {width}

BoxVolumeIntent tell me the volume of a box

BoxVolumeIntent what is the volume of a box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

**Steps**

1. First I needed to create a dialog model using the Amazon Skill Builder. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use it on the Skill Builder page.
2. I then needed to figure out how flask -ask handled multi - turn dialogs. The solution is the following block of code that I found while browsing through the issues of the repository.

   ```
   dialog_state = get_dialog_state()
       if dialog_state != "COMPLETED":
           return delegate(speech=None)
   ```

   Where the label dialog_state is set to the value of the function get_dialog_state(). If we go into the if statement we return a delegate object which delegates back to the Alexa Voice Service that another prompt is required to fulfill the intent.

The get_dialog_state() function looks like this

```
def get_dialog_state:
    return session['dialogState']
```

Place the block of code in step 2 anywhere you intend to have a multi-turn dialog. After all of the prompts have been satisfied handle what you would do with that data. Also include any error checking that is required.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the steps outlined in @bradleyGamiMarques' answer, I found I needed to include the `delegate` class along with the other Flask-Ask classes I'm using.

```
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session, context, delegate
```

A hangup I experienced here was that in this instance my IDE (PyCharm) flagged `delegate` as an "unresolved reference." I ignored that, though, after manually confirming its existence and everything works out.

Answer (score 0):

One more change in addition to importing delegate from flask-ask

Instead of

```
if dialog_state != "COMPLETED":
        return delegate(speech=None)
```

Use

```
if dialog_state != "COMPLETED":
        return delegate()
```